# How to return nested json by Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework, nested

I have data inside postgres database like this

[image]

and I want to create rest api to return nested json like this

```
[
{
    "machine": "MC1",
    "work"   : [
                 {
                    "title": "21TCE20200910",
                    "subTitle1": "INSERT CORE",
                    "subTitle2": "P20200910-001",
                    "subTitle3": "DRAW20200910",
                    "status": 0,
                    "delay": 2
                 },
                 {
                    "title": "21TCE20200910",
                    "subTitle1": "INSERT CORE",
                    "subTitle2": "P20200910-001",
                    "subTitle3": "DRAW20200912",
                    "status": 1,
                    "delay": 1
                 }
               ]
    
},
{
    "machine": "MC2",
    "work"   : [
                 {
                    "title": "21TCE20200911",
                    "subTitle1": "SCREW",
                    "subTitle2": "P20200910-001",
                    "subTitle3": "DRAW20200910",
                    "status": 1,
                    "delay": 2
                 }
               ]
    
},
{
    "machine": "MC3",
    "work"   : [
                 {
                    "title": "21TCE20200913",
                    "subTitle1": "INSERT FIX",
                    "subTitle2": "P20200910-001",
                    "subTitle3": "DRAW20200910",
                    "status": 0,
                    "delay": 1
                 }
               ]
    
}
```

]

Currently I can only return normal json for each record but I want to group and return nested json like above any help would be appreciate

these below are my codes
model.py

```
    from django.db import models
    class MachineSchedule(models.Model):
        machine = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        title   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        subTitle1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        subTitle2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        subTitle3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        status = models.IntegerField(1)
        delay = models.IntegerField(1)
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from rest_framework import generics
    from .models import MachineSchedule
    from .serializers import MachineScheduleSerializer
    class MachineScheduleListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = MachineScheduleSerializer
          model = MachineSchedule
            fields = '__all__'
```

serializers.py

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import MachineAllocate
    
    class MachineAllocateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = MachineAllocate
            fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: I've posted it below thanks!

Comment: An answer is not the place to put your code. Please move it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#models
class Work(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subTitle1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subTitle2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subTitle3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.IntegerField(1)
    delay = models.IntegerField(1)

class MachineSchedule(models.Model):
    machine = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='work')

#serializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class WorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = MachineAllo
    fields = '__all__'

class MachineScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    work = WorkSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
    model = MachineAllo
    fields = '__all__'

#views
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import MachineSchedule
from .serializers import MachineScheduleSerializer

class MachineScheduleListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MachineScheduleSerializer
    model = MachineSchedule
    fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it show error like this when open api
ProgrammingError

column app_mc_schedule_machineschedule.work_id does not exist